# What does "just" mean in this sentence

Tags: word-meaning

**A boy is looking for a bank**

**Boy**: Oh, this must be a bank. I'll **just** make sure.

What does that notice say? Uh, yes. Bank of the World.

Good. What does this notice say? Closed.

---

What does "**just**" mean in this sentence"

Comment: It means _'simply'_.

Comment: Please tell us the source of this monologue  (It is not normal for people to talk to themselves like this, in any language)

Answer (score 1):

In this sense it's a softening word, and it acts in the sense of *this won't take a moment*, *it's probably fine but...*, *I'm going to do this small thing* etc. It can be used to make requests less demanding - here it's not actually a request, but you can think of it like the person is going to check the building, but they don't want to seem rude or inconsiderate of the people they're with. It's more *I'll be right back!* than *I'm going over there!*

*Just* also has a sense of *right now* when you're talking about the present, so the person is effectively saying "I'm going to check it right now, I'll be back!"

Comment: True, but *I'm **just** going to check it **next time*** doesn't imply I'll be doing it anytime soon. It just means that when I ***do*** do it again, I won't do anything more than simply "check" it (I won't be doing any of the additional procedures that I did with the current one).

Comment: Oh yeah, but you're not talking about the present in that case ;) So that's more of the *only* sense, more than the *be right back* sense (I keep thinking of example phrases that still include *just*, it's such a useful word)

Comment: I just thought the point was worth making for the benefit of any *learners* who might read it, since many learners ***just might*** understand *I'm going to = I **am** going to...* as a "Present Tense" utterance. Or *many learners **might just**...*, with a slightly different implication. It's just such a handy word!

Comment: I see what you mean, yeah - it has a lot of uses, so it's definitely worth making people aware that there's more to it than what I covered!

Answer (score 0):

According to Merriam-Webster:

> **[Just](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/just):**
> **Sense 3a:-**
> Only, Simply.
> For example:
>
> - *"Just last year"*
> - *"just be yourself"*

So, this is what the boy tells:

> *"I'll **just** make sure."*

And, this is what he means:

> *"I'll **simply** make sure of it"*

You must notice that **'just'** is used as an `adverb` in this sentence.

Answer (score -1):

Just here has the meaning only. I will only check the building, it's a small task and I won't do anything else, so it won't take long.